# Gitlab CE - approvals workaround

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Hey I have Gitlab CE version and I would like to implement a job that verifies approvals from a peer. I know this feature is totally available for premium and ultimate versions. However, I already created a little hack that verifies that the person who approves the MR is different from the one who created it.

My question is: *is there a way to cancel the approval, without being manually, if there has been a change to the code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to cancel the approval, without being manually, if there has been a change to the code?

This is already [the default behavior in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#remove-all-approvals-when-commits-are-added-to-the-source-branch). When new commits are pushed the source branch of an MR, all approvals are removed.

However, if that setting is not available in GitLab Free, there is no workaround for this as only the approver can revoke their own approval. You *might* be able to make a pipeline job remove the approval using the API, if you have a personal access token for every approver available in the job, but this is quite impractical.

Comment: My $0.02 is that you will save more money in engineering hours by simply purchasing a GitLab Premium entitlement than trying to engineer around the limitations in GitLab Free.

Comment: It seems that the setting is not available... I wouldn't mind upgrading but I'm on a company account :((( Thank you very much, again!

Comment: Otherwise a possible solution will be with Graphql confirm that the last MR node is "@xxxxxx approved this merge request yy minutes ago"